# Problem updating to latest version of Sprout SEO

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

I updated Sprout SEO on our development site, but get the following error when trying to view the site:

*Craft\TemplatesService and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "setTemplatesPath".*

I can access the Control Panel, but navigating within the Sprout SEO tab gets me the following error:

*Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "?".*

We are not on the latest version of Craft (Pro 2.5.2754) for a few reasons - not ideal, I know. Can anyone let me know where I should look to resolve this, or if it's a compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to recreate your issue. The error caused by an older version of Twig.

The error should be fixed by upgrading to [Craft 2.6.2771](https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-6-2771)